# how to make left join in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

this is my first model

```
class DipPegawai(models.Model):
    PegID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    PegNamaLengkap = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    PegUnitKerja = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

and this is my second model

```
class DipHonorKegiatanPeg(models.Model):
    KegID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    PegID = models.ForeignKey(DipPegawai, blank=True,null=True)
    KegNama = models.Charfield(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
```

i want to make left join with this model, something like this in mysql query

```
SELECT PegNamaLengkap, KegNama_id
FROM karyawan_dippegawai AS k LEFT JOIN honorkegiatanpeg_diphonorkegiatanpeg AS h ON k.PegID = h.PegID_id
WHERE PegUnitKerja = 3
GROUP BY k.PegID
```

how to make left join with django orm same like mysql query above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
DipPegawai.objects.filter(PegUnitKerja=3).values_list.('pegnamalengkap', 'diphonorkegiatanpeg_kegnama')
```

Tell me if that worked for you.
You can print your raw query using `print(your_var_here.query)`. Remember put your query into a var

Answer (score 0):

```
DipHonorKegiatanPeg.objects.filter(PegID__PegUnitKerja=3).values('PegID__PegNamaLengkap', 'KegNama_id')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.